# Proving existence and uniqueness of nonlinear ODE system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In a problem, I'm asked to prove the existence and uniqueness of a continuus solution to the nonlinear ode
$$u''(t)+\frac{3}{t}u'(t) = -t^2e^{u(t)},\hspace{0.2in}u(0) = 0,$$
for some interval $0<t<\delta.$

My approach would be to rewrite as a nonlinear system and attempt to invoke the Contraction Mapping theorem.  Writing as a first order system gives
$$u'(t) = v(t),$$
$$v'(t) = -\frac{3}{t}v(t)-t^2e^{u(t)}.$$

However, here I'm stuck.  Do I need to linearize the system using a Jacobian matrix?  Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to specify $u'(0)$ as well.

Comment: Ok @RobertLewis, suppose that $u'(0) = C$, some constant for now.